# How to place an element on top of other

Tags: html, css

I want to place an element on top of other without modifying the position of the second. I mean:

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 align-content: baseline;
 padding: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: blue;
}

.base {
  color: black;
}

.top {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="base">
    base
    <div class="top">
      should be on top
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the `should be on top` div to be placed above the `base` div, and the `base` div to still be aligned the way it does. I have tried using relative positioning and giving negative bottom values but it isn't that responsive. This is how i want them to be, except for `base` should keep the previous position:

```css
    .container {
     display: flex;
     align-content: baseline;
     padding: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     background-color: blue;
    }

    .base {
      color: black;
    }

    .top {
      color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    should be on top
    <div class="base">
      base
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`should be ontop` div have to be on top of `base`, and `base` where it was before. How can I do this?
This is what I was trying:

```css
    .container {
     display: flex;
     align-content: baseline;
     padding: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     background-color: blue;
    }

    .base {
      color: black;
    }

    .top {
      position: relative;
      color: red;
      bottom: 4.8em;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="base">
        base
        <div class="top">
          should be on top
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

That's how I want them to be placed. But if the # of lines of `should be ontop` div changes then it overflow above of the `base` div. I think it could be done using js, but I prefer it was only with css. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have figured out a way to do this. Its not the best css code but at least it did the trick.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-content: baseline;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.base {
    position: relative;
    color: black;
}

.top-container {
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="base">
        base
        <div class="top-container">
          <div class="top">
            should be on top
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I created a `top-container` inside the `base` div, with `height` && `top` = 0, so when I did `bottom: 0` in my `top` div, it placed on top of `base` no matter how large any of them was. Hope it works for everyone else. Any improvement is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

*Looks like I misunderstood the question. I've updated the answer to reflect those changes.*

The parent div must have a position of `relative` and the inside div a position of `absolute`. So the `above` div becomes "absolute" relative to `base` div.

Now you need to specify how much "above" you need the div to be, because there is no other way to remove an element from the flow and position it elsewhere. (unless you're using javascript)

Here's how your code may look like:

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 align-content: baseline;
 padding: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: blue;
}

.base {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
}

.above {
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="base">
    base
    <div class="above">
      should be above
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I really mean `on top`. English isn't my first languaje :(

Comment: @Theia No worries. English isn't my first language either, Looks like I misunderstood the question too. I've updated my answer, please take a look! :)

Comment: That is like what I was trying before, but using, `bottom` instead. The problem is that if the lines of the upper div changes, it doesn't looks right

Comment: @Theia unfortunately there is no better way I am aware of. To make it better you'll either have to change your html structure or use javascript.

Comment: I don't mind changing the structure of the html, just that the `ontop` to be relative positioned to the `base`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly this is what you want:

```css
.container {
     display: flex;
     align-content: baseline;
     padding: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     background-color: blue;
      position: relative;
      justify-content: center;
      position: rela
    }

    .base {
      color: black;
    }

    .top {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
      color: red;
      bottom: 4.8em;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="base">
        base
        <div class="top">
          should be on top
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

1. I added `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center` properties to `.container` element so the `.base` element is always centred.
2. I added `absolute` positioning to `.top` element so it's always positioned at the top. I also added `relative` positioning to `.container` so the absolute position og `.top` element is based on the position of `.container`. That's how absolute positioning works (it's relative to first element with positioning different than `static`).
3. I added `text-align: center` to `.top` so the text is centred.

You can try to add more lines to `.top` element to see if this is expected behaviour.

Comment: The problems still persists. If the `top` div content increase considerably. it overflows above the `base` div. like this: https://codepen.io/Theiades/pen/qVeNEB

Comment: Can you please explain what do you expect in this case? Pushing `.base` down?